# Which statistical method should use to compare two dependent data (from 1 patient) but not paired?

Tags: categorical-data, independence

I want to compare the number of lesions worsening and non worsening on superior to inferior side of the eye of a group of patients. I want to compare if the proportional results (the total sum of worsening and total sum of non worsening in the superior vs inferior side ) have a significant difference. In my data I have:

- worsening 2618 (66.8%) INFERIOR
- non worsening 1298 (33.1) INFERIOR
- worsening 2981 71.4% SUPERIOR
- non worsening 1190 28.5% SUPERIOR

Which method should I use since these proportions are dependent (it comes from the same patient), but not paired(there is no before after rather different locations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are definitely paired. Pairing is not restricted to 'before-after' comparisons.

Anything where within-pair values (like values from two locations on a single patient) would tend to be more alike than out-pair values (values from the corresponding two locations on two different patients) are paired.

(This is a disturbingly common error -- presumably there's some widely-used elementary books promulgating this mistaken notion.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, however when I look up in the literature which  method use to compare proportions I found chi square for independent variables, which method should i used for proportions if these are dependent variables?

Comment: It's not clear what your null and alternative hypothesis is when comparing four proportions. Can you clarify?  (It will likely be some form of chi-squared test, but more information is needed). Is the fact that the first pair of percentages and the second pair don't quite add to 100% just rounding error or is there a (tiny) third category?

Comment: You are right, there was a rounding error, well I like to compare first the proportions of worsening category (INF 66.9 vs SUP 71.5) and compare the proportions of non worsening as well (INF 33.1 vs SUP 28.5) and I would have two result for statistical significance

Comment: Thanks for the clarification The two comparisons are dependent, since 66.9 = 100-33.1 and 28.5 = 100-71.5. If one is different it would imply that the other is.

Comment: I wasn't clear sorry about that, My null hypothesis: no difference in proportions between sup e inf, I want to compare just two proportions but the chi square didn't seem appropriate because it assumes these 2 proportions are independent when in fact are dependent hence my confussion. I really appreciate your help Glen_b!!